# How to select element by class when multiple elements match?

Tags: automated-testing

If I select flight departure time with class name through selenium in python but class name is used by both div & span tags it fails.

How can I select only one element type (div) and not sdpans.

my code is:

```
[element.text for element in self.browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "dept-time")]
```

Answer (score 3):

To select the *div* with the class you can use css (preferred for readability)

```
BY.css
```

> Example

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS, 'div.dept-time')
```

---

or xpath

```
BY.xpath
```

> Example

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class=dept-time]
```

---

or if there are *multiple* classes for that element, use

```
contains
```

> Example

```
//div[contains(@class, 'dept-time')]
```

If more than 1 div element with that class exist and you want the *first* one you can also use:

```
[1]
```

> Example (XPATH)

```
//div[@class='dept-time'])[1]
```

> Example (CSS)

```
div.dept-time:first
```

Comment: i want to select only div tag through class name but i run my API its scraps both data because class name is same in both tag then how to select only div class name.   <div class="dept-time">11:10</div>  not  <span class="dept-time">11:10</span>

Comment: Yes my code here select only div's **as shown**  What do you not understand about it?

Comment: Are you getting a multiple matches error and assuming it is finding div's as well as span's perhaps ?  If so it will be because there are multiple **div's** with that class (class is a clue too as classes are applied to multiple elements where as id's are unique).

Answer (score 0):

Using css selectors, instead of class, the syntax to select the tag with a specific class/attribute is `tag[attribute='value']`. So in your case:

`[element.text for element in self.browser.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='dept-time']")]`

More information on css selectors: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp